# Codeigniter 3 order_by dopings

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 4 types of `doping`.
I need some sorting on the categories page.
Those with doping types 1 and 4 will be listed as DESC at the top, those with type 1 at the bottom, those with type 4 at the bottom and normal products at the last row, according to their formation date.

Finally, I will need to use the `doping` type in the view so that I can write the doping name.

```
public function getdopingoneandfor($category_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('products.*, products.id as product_id, products_details.price as product_price');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->join('products_details', 'products_details.product_id = products.id');
        $this->db->join('dopings', 'dopings.product_id = products.id');
        $this->db->where('products.status', 1);
        $this->db->where_in('dopings.type', array(1, 4));
        $this->db->where('dopings.end_date >= CURDATE()');
        $this->db->where('products.category_id', $category_id);
        $this->db->group_by('products.id');
        $this->db->order_by('MAX(dopings.created_at)', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of querying does not seem possible, and extending the query is extremely harmful.
I recommend you divide it into pieces.
If your client is very insistent on this issue, offer not to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).